# PHP StdObject How to extract nested array

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to get status "N" in this stdObject using PHP. I have looked at all solutions on stackoverflow but my structure is more complex than their nested arrays.

It is not producing the value I want.   At first, I want to find "N" then once I had this, I wanted to develop further to use a foreach loop to count the number of N's in each stdobject. BUT I am still struggling on base 1.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
Array
(
    [result_count] => 4
    [total_count] => 4
    [next_offset] => 4
    [entry_list] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [module_name] => M1
                    [name_value_list] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => id
                                    [value] => 1
                                )

                            [client] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => client
                                    [value] => Disney
                                )

                            [minimum] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => minimum
                                    [value] => 3
                                )

                            [status] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => status
                                    [value] => N
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [module_name] => MB1
                    [name_value_list] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => id
                                    [value] => 2
                                )

                            [client] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => client
                                    [value] => test
                                )

                            [minimum] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => minimum
                                    [value] => 4
                                )

                            [green_status] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => green_status
                                    [value] => N
                                )

                        )

                )

    [relationship_list] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [link_list] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [link_list] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [link_list] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [link_list] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: According to the outermost `Array()`, this doesn't seem to be an stdObject, but an ordinary array instead.

Comment: I don't see any `object` here, it's just a multidimensional array. `$array[entry_list][0][name_value_list][status][value]`

Comment: Also, please show us the code that you tried so far.

Comment: Your structure is just a nested array structure, not an `stdClass` (`stdObject` does not exist. Sounds like you need to recursively iterate over your array structure - look at PHP's built-in iterators including `RecursiveArrayIterator`, and `FilterIterator`. They can be unwieldy to use but you should find helpfu answers here on SO

Comment: Or maybe it's more simple - it's hard to tell exactly from the phrasing of your question. Can you clarify what result you expect to get when processing the above structure?

Comment: Here is my code:$data = json_decode(json_encode($get_list), true);

   echo "<pre>";


    print_r($data);


    echo "</pre>";

Comment: I also did a foreach loop to extract value but it is only on top level of the array. I cannot get inside anything in entry_list array and within the inner levels.

Comment: @Connum  (tagged my code)

Comment: @DarraghEnright thanks, I'll look into this now.

Comment: So what is in `$get_list` and why are you first using `json_encode()` and then `json_decode()` on it?!

Comment: @DarraghEnright  Two arrays contain "N" for the key "green_status".  When I add more records, this produces more elements in the array. If there is 2 N's out of 5 records. I want to count only those elements with "N".    So the value should be: 2. I simplified the array because I have lots of arrays.

Comment: @Connum $get_list is being retrieved from server using curl and headers.  $json_encode produces JSON from the array when retrieving records. $json_decode produces the array as highlight in the above thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multidimensional array. if you want to get statuses in array dynamically:

```
<?php 
foreach($arr['entry_list'] as $entry){
    foreach($entry as $entryKey => $entryValue){
        if(strpos($entryKey, "status") !== false){
            //Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

If is static array you can access:

```
<?php 
var_dump($arr["entry_list"][0]["status"]);
var_dump($arr["entry_list"][1]["green_status"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response 4EACH, I had the similar idea as you posted but slightly different. Your results produces NULL NULL. Whereas I had Result: Array

Comment: Which one you tried ? you need the static or dynamic solution ?

Comment: I tried both.  I have been working mostly with dynamic, but I get this Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error. same for a very simple forloop.

Comment: foreach ($data as $key => $value2)
  {
echo $value2[result_count];
}    //This works because I need this figure.   But when I work down the level. I get the result: Array   but not the key and value within the Array

Comment: use `var_dump` instead of `echo`, you can't echo an Array

Comment: Oh..I see. Some reason array solutions do not appear to work for me.If that is the case between me encoding and decoding between different formats, I may have to debug a little bit more again. Thanks!

Comment: Have a nice coding ! hope that i help to you

Comment: Thanks! You pointed me into the right direction. Hopefully I can solve it :)

Comment: Thanks! I have solved it. I had to tweak your code, but generally the idea worked. It had 5/6 deep level or arrays so I had to narrow it down as I went along.     When I reach 15, I will award you with the points you deserve.   Thank you again for being proactive and taking initiative to provide solutions